# Area of the surface $f(x,y)=25-x^2-y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have to calculate the area of the surface

$$f(x,y)=25-x^2-y^2$$

that lies over the $xy$ plane. What I did was applying $$A = \int \int \sqrt{1+f_x^2+f^2_y} dA$$

which becomes

$$\int \int \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} dA$$

but how can I determie the limits of integration? I tried with polar coordinates $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$ so it transofrms to

$$\int \int \sqrt{1+4r^2} d\theta rdr$$

but I still have the same problem. I get that $\theta$ goes form $0$ to $2\pi$ but what about the limits of r and how to determine the range of z. Does it becomes a triple integral then?

Comment: This is a circle with radius $5$.

Comment: to compute a value of an [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) you need start with a definite integral, not an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=25-x^2-y^2$ surface is a circle with $0 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 5^2$

So here is how the bounds will look: $A = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{5} rdrd\theta$

Comment: And regarding the part of area that lies over the $xy$ plane, I just need to add another parameter $z$ from $0$ to $25$, right?

Comment: You have to find the area of this surface and it lies in $XY$ plane. This is a 2D question. So there is no $z$.